# How to install JailKit?

Tags: compiling

I want to install `jailkit` in ubuntu http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=248724

so i have downloaded jailkit http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#download

after downloading I did tar

then `cd` in to directory

```
./configure

make
```

(error)

## How do i install it ?

Ii am installing (compile) it on Ubuntu server 11.10

## UPDATE

I found out, how to start make:

(as root)

```
make

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/one/jailkit-2.14/src'

gcc   -lpthread  -o jk_socketd jk_socketd.o jk_lib.o utils.o iniparser.o

jk_socketd.o: In function `main':

/home/one/jailkit-2.14/src/jk_socketd.c:474: undefined reference to `pthread_create'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[1]: *** [jk_socketd] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/one/jailkit-2.14/src'

make: *** [all] Error 2

root@ubuntu:/home/one/jailkit-2.14#
```

Comment: We need to see the error from when you try to `make`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep I just got exactly the same on mine. The linker isn't getting the correct flags.

```
make clean
export LDFLAGS="-pthread"
./configure && make
```

Comment: ./configure && make > then make install ? or its installed ?

Comment: Sorry, yes you'll need to do a (sudo) `make install` afterwards if you want to install it system-wide

Answer (score 3):

To avoid compilation errors, there is a PPA (`ppa:jailkit/ppa`) for jailkit available.

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/41)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to install JailKit

```
apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool flex bison debhelper binutils-gold
cd /tmp
wget http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit-2.20.tar.gz
tar xvfz jailkit-2.20.tar.gz
cd jailkit-2.20 ./debian/rules binary
```

You can now install the Jailkit .deb package as follows:

```
cd ..
dpkg -i jailkit_2.20-1_*.deb
```

[Help " 19 Install Jailkit "](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p5)